# divide a document in sections

Tags: python, nltk, text-mining, information-extraction

I have the data that is processed from Apache tika so i have plan text, what i am trying to do is to save each section in a different array, i am having trouble in identifying the sections.

showing different section with bullet point

*Resume*

- > Name
  >
  > Location, city
  >
  > Phone: *********
  >
  > Email: myemail@email.
- > OBJECTIVE
  >
  > text
- > EDUCATION AND QUALIFICATION
  >   • text - location, country
- > SKILLS
  >
  > • skills

i am expecting anything that may help me find anything related to this, for example any library, better word to search. I am working with python and using libraries nltk , spacy ,tika

*not relevant to the question(there are few related question(not answered) in my understanding it will be really hard and won't be simple to make it work so i am just looking for the hints to look in better direction.)*

Comment: If it's a plain text file can you just open it in python using open() then readline/readlines command depending on the format of the text file?

Comment: @AlexWhite the actual resume is not in the bullet points its just to clear how i am differentiating sections, i am having trouble in identifying the sections, sorry this was not clear in the question

Comment: I used this blog to get what I was looking for https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/05/text-mining-information-resume.html